# PYTHONPATH not set automatically in virtualenvs

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualenv

I installed a virtualbox with xubuntu-16.04.2-desktop on windows 10.
when I create an env running a mezzanine app, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 7, in <module>
from mezzanine.utils.conf import real_project_name
ImportError: No module named 'mezzanine'
```

the same when I try to import modules:

```
(test) mauri@bison:~$ python -c "import django"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

the problem seems to be the PYTHONPATh, not set correctly.
If i set it manually, everything works fine.

```
(test) mauri@bison:~$ export 
PYTHONPATH="/home/mauri/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/"
(test) mauri@bison:~$ python -c "import django"
(test) mauri@bison:~$ env
XDG_VTNR=7
LC_PAPER=cs_CZ.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=cs_CZ.UTF-8
 XDG_SESSION_ID=c1
....
```

any idea why the PYTHONPATH is not set automatically when I create envs?

thank you so much, and sorry if I miss anything in the explaination, I m pretty new in this field.

Comment: The ``PYTHONPATH`` environment doesn't get set when you activate a virtual environment. That isn't how it works. Run ``python`` and do ``import sys; print(sys.path)``, the ``site-packages`` directory should be automatically added.

Comment: this is the result

`(test) mauri@bison:~$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your bash* if you have any `alias` overriding the python setup. You can easily check with the command `alias` from bash:

```
$ alias
alias ll='ls -alh'
alias ls='ls -G'
...
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Removed the alias, everything now works perfectly.